# Is there a way to print only the dictionary in all_lists based on the input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am defining a list of dictionaries and I need to print only the one dictionary based on my input in `check_if_in_list`

```
first_list = {'a':'1','b':'2'}
second_list = {'a':'10','b':'20'}

all_lists =[first_list, second_list]

for element in all_lists:
  check_if_in_list = input('give a valid number')
  if check_if_in_list = (item['a'] for item in all_lists):
```

I need something like that

`print(element where item['a]=check_if_in_list)`

for example if I enter '1' in input in `check_if_in_list`, the print should be :

```
{'a':'1','b':'2'}
```

Comment: This is not valid Python code.

Comment: @ScottHunter yes i know but i need something like that this is what i meant with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the output you require. If I have interpreted your requirement correctly, it's actually much simpler than the (I assume) semi-pseudocode that you posted.

```
first_dict = {'a':'1','b':'2'}
second_dict = {'a':'10','b':'20'}

all_dicts =[first_dict, second_dict]

check_if_in_list = input('give a valid number')
for element in all_lists:
    if check_if_in_list == element['a']:
        print(element)
```

If you need it as a comprehension, this would work:

```
print(*[element for element in all_lists if element['a'] == check_if_in_list])
```

This utilises [star-unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-a-function-call) to return the values of the list for printing, which should either be a dictionary or nothing in your case. (Thanks to @HampusLarsson for the reminder).

If your original code, you're looping over all_lists twice, which is unnecessary.